# INSERT INTO if condition is satisfied

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to save the array `$solution` into the SQL table only if `$solution[$i][0]` belongs to the result of the query `SELECT num_arr FROM Schedule WHERE num_arr<>''`. If it does not belong to it, then the row $i must be not saved in the SQL table. The below-provided query seems to be incorrect. How do I implement the described task? What would be the correct approach to do this?

```
$query_land = "INSERT INTO `Sequence` (`num_arr`,`start`,`fin`,`way_id`) 
               VALUES ('".$solution[$i][0]."','".$solution[$i][1]."',
                                   '".$solution[$i][2]."','".$solution[$i][3]."') 
               WHERE '".$solution[$i][0]."' IN (SELECT num_arr 
                                                FROM Schedule 
                                                WHERE num_arr<>'')";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `INSERT` statment has two variations:

```
INSERT INTO tableX
    (a, b, c, ...)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 3, ...) ;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO tableX
    (a, b, c, ...)
SELECT
    1, 2, 3
FROM
    ... ;             --- the same or another table or many tables
```

The `dual` is a system table with exactly 1 row. It can be used for various things. Here it's used so a `VALUES (...)` is rewritten as a `SELECT ...` where we don't have any suitable table to put in the `FROM` clause:

```
$query_land = "INSERT INTO `Sequence` (`num_arr`,`start`,`fin`,`way_id`) 
               SELECT '".$solution[$i][0]."','".$solution[$i][1]."',
                      '".$solution[$i][2]."','".$solution[$i][3]."'
               FROM dual 
               WHERE '".$solution[$i][0]."' IN (SELECT num_arr 
                                                FROM Schedule 
                                                WHERE num_arr<>'')";
```

Comment: @ypercube: What is 'dual' in your code? The values of the array solutions are not stored yet in any other SQL table.

Comment: @YouKuper: The DUAL table is a special one-row table present by default in all MySQL database installations

Comment: Oh,then this solution is perfect.