# Assign DATETIME a value on INSERT to DB based on BETWEEN function values

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to, when inserting a new record to TABLE 1, assign DATETIME a value based on another tables values, but having trouble putting it all together.

TABLE1 has interval_id and submit_date columns (and many others)

TABLE2 has interval_id, begin_time, and end_time

Example:

- INSERT statement with DATETIME of 2012-10-24 07:29:41
- Peel off just the TIME
- Reference the interval_id's in both tables
- Look up where TIME falls between T2.begin_time and T2.end_time
  (06:00:00 and 07:59:59 in this case)
- once determined,assign the corresponding value to it in T1.interval_id

So far:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (null, now())
WHERE
  DATE(submit_date) = curdate()
  AND TIME(submit_date)
```

----not sure on coding here to compare TIME to the begin and end time column data----

full insert statement:

```
    $sql        = "INSERT INTO `summary` VALUES (null,'$user_id','$task_id',NOW(),'$tcompleted_id','$minutes_id','$hourinterval_id')
                   SELECT NOW(), hourinterval_id 
                   FROM `hour_interval` H
                   WHERE TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN H.start_hour AND H.end_hour LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: An `INSERT` statement is for new rows only, and therefore has no `WHERE` clause. Do you mean to update existing rows?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The syntax is incorrect, but you can `INSERT` values based on the result of a `SELECT` statement which would support a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the results of a `SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE1`(curdate, interval_id)
SELECT now(), inteval_id FROM `TABLE2` t2 
WHERE TIME(now()) BETWEEN t2.start_time AND t2.end_time LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The select statement works, but I keep getting a syntax error?  I'll post my full insert above.

Comment: Full error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT NOW(), hourinterval_id FROM `hour_interval` H WHERE TI' at line 2

Comment: What is your full sql statement?

Comment: `hour_interval H` is the same as `hour_interval AS H` and doublesharp used `t2` not `H`.

Comment: t2 was for table2..test table and not used in my real statement.  h is the alias for hour_interval, which is correct.

Comment: @Mike; You can't have both `VALUES` and `SELECT` in an `INSERT` statement. try again the code that doublesharp suggests. Without `VALUES`

Comment: Tried that too...still getting an error:  MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null,'5','5',NOW(),'1','2','') SELECT NOW(), hourinterval_id ' at line 1

Comment: `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT NULL, '$user_id', '$task_id', NOW(), '$tcompleted_id', '$minutes_id', hourinterval_id FROM table2 WHERE ...`

Comment: @ypercube That worked (awesome thanks!!), but can you explain why?  I don't fully understand the syntax.

Comment: @Mike: The `INSERT` statement has [2 variations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180259/insert-into-if-condition-is-satisfied/12180402#12180402)